# Command line client to resolve win64 stack trace (with access to a symbol server)

Tags: c++, windbg, stack-trace

I have a gazillion windows stack traces in the following form (in text files):

```
MyApplication 0x00000000678d0000 + 1093618 
MyApplication 0x00000000678d0000 + 106e1fd 
MyApplication 0x00000000678d0000 + 1089314 
MyApplication 0x00000000678d0000 + 149554e 
MyApplication 0x00000000678d0000 + 3a5e57 
MyApplication 0x00000000678d0000 + 1cec589 
MyApplication 0x00000000678d0000 + 149fd17 
MyApplication 0x00000000678d0000 + c7e557 
KERNEL32 0x00000000152e0000 + 17bd4 
ntdll 0x00000000153e0000 + 6ced1
```

And I also have a set up symbol server with the (compressed) symbol informations.

Is there a way to have some script (probably utilizing some command line command from windbg?) to translate the addresses into source code lines? I never worked with stack traces outside Visual Studio, so any pointer in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: On Linux I would have pointed to `addr2line`. I don't know of a Windows equivalent, but I'm sure there must be one.

Comment: Do you have a build identifier of each stack trace? You will need that to grab the correct symbol information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the correct pdb for your MyApplication.exe

you can use the dbh.exe that comes with windbg package

```
:\>dbh dumpfuncs.exe laddr 1001000

   file : c:\users\xx\source\repos\dumpfuncs\dumpfuncs.cpp
   line : 5
   addr :  1001000
    key : 00000000
disp : 0

:\>tail -n+5 dumpfuncs.cpp |head -1
__declspec ( noinline ) LPSTR CmdLn(void) {

:\>dbh dumpfuncs.exe m 1001000

 index            address     name
   148            1001000 :   CmdLn

:\>
```

code below should behave similar to Jesper Juhl's comment about addr2line

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib,"dbghelp.lib")
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if( argc != 3) {
        printf("usage %s \"Module/Path\" \"Offset as hex 0x1010\"\n",argv[0]);
        return FALSE;
    }
    DWORD64 offset = _strtoui64(argv[2], NULL, 16);
    SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_UNDNAME | SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS |SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES);
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    if (!SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, FALSE))    {
        printf("SymInitialize returned error : %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }    
    DWORD64 ModBase = SymLoadModuleEx (hProcess,NULL, argv[1], NULL,0,0,NULL,0);
    if( (ModBase == 0) && (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS) )    {
        printf("SymLoadModuleEx returned error : %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;        
    }
    DWORD64 SymAddr = ModBase + offset;
    printf("Module %s Loaded At 0x%I64x SymAddr = 0x%I64x\n",argv[1],ModBase ,SymAddr);
    IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line ={0};
    line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64);
    DWORD dwDisplacement =0;
    if(!SymGetLineFromAddr64(hProcess, SymAddr, &dwDisplacement, &line)){
        printf("SymGetLineFromAddr64 returned error : %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    printf("Source= %s # %u @ %I64x\n",line.FileName,line.LineNumber,line.Address);
    std::ifstream fs;
    fs.open(line.FileName);
    if(fs.is_open()){
        std::string buff;
        unsigned  int lineno = 0;
        while (lineno != line.LineNumber && getline(fs, buff)){
            ++lineno;
        }
        printf("%s\n",buff.c_str());
        fs.close();
    }else{
        printf("cannot open %s\n",line.FileName);        
    }
}
```

compiled and executed

```
:\>bld.bat AddrToLineWin

:\>cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /EHsc /nologo /Od AddrToLineWin.cpp /link /nologo /release
AddrToLineWin.cpp

:\>AddrToLineWin.exe ..\dumpfuncs\dumpfuncs.exe 0x1010
Module ..\dumpfuncs\dumpfuncs.exe Loaded At 0x400000 SymAddr = 0x401010
Source= c:\users\xx\source\repos\dumpfuncs\dumpfuncs.cpp # 8 @ 401010
__declspec ( noinline ) LPSTR FileName (void) {

:\>AddrToLineWin.exe ..\dumpfuncs\dumpfuncs.exe 0x1008
Module ..\dumpfuncs\dumpfuncs.exe Loaded At 0x400000 SymAddr = 0x401008
Source= c:\users\xx\source\repos\dumpfuncs\dumpfuncs.cpp # 6 @ 401003
    return GetCommandLineA();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ln MyApplication + 0n1093618
```

Notice that for decimal (non-hex) values use 0n followed by the number.
If you have the symbols this command will give you function and source code line number.

If it is managed code it will not work though.
You have to use SOS instead:

```
!ip2md MyApplication + 0n1093618
```